# Dynamic configuration of multiple streams with nginx-rtmp-server

Tags: nginx, video, video-streaming, http-live-streaming, rtmp

I need to build an application that has a many-to-many correspondence between users and cameras. The server needs to pull the RTMP streams from the cameras and stream them to the users (web and mobile applications) as HLS.

I considered using nginx-rtmp-server but the problems I faced were:

- I'm having to configure each camera stream manually (I would prefer to add/remove streams programmatically)
- User requests to streams need to be authorized by my application

Is there a way to achieve the above with nginx-rtmp-server or any other library? I think that a library that can be integrated with my application and configured dynamically will do the job. Any suggestions there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question 2 : I have no idea about authorization.

Question 1 :
For **nginx-rtmp-server** you can use in nginx

```
rtmp {
        server {
                listen 1935;
                chunk_size 4096;
                application live {
                        live on;
                        record off;
                }
        }
}
```

Here you register an application called **live**.

Now you can use it for multiple camera like :

```
rtmp://{ip address}:1935/live/{camera_id}
```