# More than one stream on single RTMP Application

Tags: nginx, http-live-streaming, rtmp

Iam currently setting up an RTMP Streaming server. The Server runs nginx with an RTMP module.

This Works like the following:

[image]

- An OBS sends the RTMP stream to a application on the Server.
- The Application checks the streamers identity and allows streaming if correct.
- The stream can be watched by a website.

As u can see I have multiple applications for each and every streamer.
But I want a single Application for all streamers.

I prepared the nginx config like this.

```
rtmp {
        server {
                listen 1935;
                chunk_size 4096;

                hls on;
                hls_path /***/hls0;
                hls_nested on;
                hls_fragment 2s;
                hls_playlist_length 600s;
                hls_fragment_naming system;

 application test {
  live on;
  record off;
  on_publish http://localhost/php/***.php;
  on_publish_done http://localhost/php/***.php
}
[...]
```

Now everything is prepared but works for only one streamer at a time.
2 diffrent streamers are accepted (app returns http code 200) but the second one couldnt start streaming.

Is there a way to get this going?

Answer (score 1):

nginx will not do that for you. To accomplish this you need to know if a streamer is currently streaming in order to reject the second connection. The application need to keep a record of all streams in a database, or a in memory map, check on on_publish and respond to nginx with a 200, or other code to reject.

Comment: hey, thanks for ur answer, but I actually WANT to allow 2 streamers at the same time. Sounds like its not possible?

Comment: Ever stream needs some form of unique identifier. for nginx-rtmp the identifier is the RTMP URL. Two things cant live at the same URL. It would be possible to modify the RTMP server to assign new streams a GUID, but you would need to code that into nginx, not your php application.

Comment: @szatmary
 What do you think about this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/64859843/14475872

Comment: @Dropye did u find the solution?